# Is footer better than a div?

Tags: html, footer

I have a div on 1 of my websites that has not been published, on another website I have a footer. Is one better than another? (I am using them the same: at the bottom of the page) Just wondering. Any ideas for what is better because I am still partly learning programming. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. You have a hidden footer and a shown footer, and you are asking if hiding the footer is better than showing it? Am I right? Clarify your question, please.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Sorry I miss write this on the first part i meant div not footer my bad thank you for noticing.

Comment: There's no noticeable difference between a footer or a div to the User. Use a footer if you're using it as a footer by definition. It's more specific and better for semantics than a div. However only use a footer if it makes sense in your page outline. Otherwise if there's no semantic tag that logically fits - use a div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The new practice is to place a header at the top and the header at the bottom, creating normally two files if it's a dynamic website and include them on your different pages but if you use a `<div>`, it will work too.

Answer (score 1):

As [Clive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66200423/6398325) said, old browsers don't support it, but even if very old browsers don't support it (firefox 4 is from 2011), you should use it as it is [semantic](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp), and being semantic helps for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Footer is a newer standard and not used by very old browser versions. See here for a Browser compatibility chart.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer